# Не могу подключить автозагрузку класса php через composer Ж PHP Fatal error: Class not found

Tags: php, json, composer, autoload

Есть 
пхп.пхп
    require_once **DIR** .'/Controllers/Requests/Producers/GetAllProducers.php';
    require_once **DIR** . '/vendor/autoload.php';

```
$r = new ClientAPI\Controllers\Requests\Producers\GetAllProducers();
$r->getAllProducers();
print_r($r);
```

Запускаю и получаю 
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'ClientAPI\Controllers\Basic\Objects\Request' not found in /var/www/html/тутматерноеслово/ClientAPI/Controllers/Requests/Producers/GetAllProducers.php on line 13

там куда он показывает выглядит так (на 13 линии экстенд Реквест)

```
namespace ClientAPI\Controllers\Requests\Producers;
use ClientAPI\Controllers\Basic\Objects\Request;
class GetAllProducers extends Request implements GetAll
{
```

ну и

```
namespace ClientAPI\Controllers\Basic\Objects;
abstract class Request
{
```

в composer.джейсон

```
{
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "ClientAPI\\": "ClientAPI",
      "ClientAPI\\Controllers\\Requests\\Producers\\Commands\\": "ClientAPI/Controllers/Requests/Producers/Commands/",
      "ClientAPI\\Controllers\\Basic\\Objects\\": "ClientAPI/Controllers/Basic/Objects/",
      "ClientAPI\\Controllers\\Basic\\Operations\\": "ClientAPI/Controllers/Basic/Operations/",
      "ClientAPI\\Controllers\\": "ClientAPI/Controllers/"
    }
  }
}
```

Не знаю как быть, раньше такого не было никогда, буду признателен за любую помощь\подсказку\ссылку... просидел над этой проблемой довольно долго =(

Comment: namespace ClientAPI\Controllers\Requests\Producers;

если убераю "extend Request" то GetAllProducers работает нормально... 

пробовал подключать не как абстрактный класс, а создавать обьект через new Request, но все так же... 

постоянно делаю дамп компосера...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас полный бред с автозагрузкой. В папке проекта создайте папку src и скопируйте туда все php-файлы которые начинаются с ClientAPI. В `composer.json` исправьте автозагрузку:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "ClientAPI\\": "src/"
    }
}
```

В вашем файле `пхп.пхп` из реквайров оставьте только

```
require PATH . '/vendor/autoload.php';
```

Comment: спасибо, помогло)